# JQuery display issue

Tags: jquery

My fieldset doesn't display onclick, what am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#More').toggle(
        function() {  $('#search', this).slideDown(); }, 
        function() {  $('#search', this).slideUp(); });
});


<div> Item 1 <a href="#" id="More">Item 2</a> Item 3


<fieldset id="search" style="display: none;">
    <form>
        <input type="text">
    </form>
</fieldset>

</div>
```

Comment: in the code shown, I don't see the fieldset display being changed from display:none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` references the event target, which in this case in the #More link. Putting `this` into your `$('#search', this)` selector is equivalent to saying:

```
$(this).find("#search")
```

Since the #search is not contained within the link, the jQuery selector never applies the slideUp or slideDown functions.

Your code should instead be the following:

```
$('#More').toggle(
        function() {  $('#search').slideDown(); }, 
        function() {  $('#search').slideUp(); }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that maybe the issue is that you are setting the context to `this`

so if you change :

```
function() {  $('#search', this).slideDown(); },
```

to

```
function() {  $('#search').slideDown(); }
```

it might start to work...